# Quicksort on a file

Tags: c, quicksort

I want to use my quicksort on a file but nothing is happening.
My quiksort work, i have try it with a array ramdomly generated.

```
typedef double *TABLEAU;


TABLEAU charge_tableau(char *s, int nb_elts) {
    FILE *f = NULL;
    TABLEAU t=malloc(nb_elts*sizeof(double));
    f=fopen("data22", "r");
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<nb_elts; i++)
        fscanf(f,"%lf", t+i);
    fclose(f);
    return t;
}


 void permuter(TABLEAU t, int i, int j){
    int tmp;
    tmp=t[i];
    t[i]=t[j];
    t[j]=tmp;
}


/* quicksort */
int partition(TABLEAU t, int m, int n){
    int pivot, i, j;
    pivot = t[m];
    i = m+1;
    for(j= m+1; j < n; j++){
        if(t[j] <= pivot){
            permuter(t, i, j);
            i++;
        }
    }

    permuter(t, m, i-1);
    return i-1;
}


 void triRapide(TABLEAU t, int nb_elts, int m, int n){
    int indPivot;
    if(m<n){
        indPivot = partition(t, m, n);
        triRapide(t, nb_elts, m, indPivot-1);
        triRapide(t, nb_elts, indPivot+1, n);
    }
 }


int main() {

    TABLEAU t;
    int nb_elts=10, m, n;
    t=charge_tableau("data22", nb_elts);
    triRapide(t, nb_elts,m,n);
    return 0;

}
```

File is like that :

0.612248 0.052802 0.442505 0.189728 0.750432 0.508627 0.491031 0.762011 0.119391 0.603284 0.394294 0.893904 0.842861 0.966140 0.920210 0.973909 0.489751 0.250233 0.671843 0.657750 0.799485 0.947670 0.492462 0.816764 0.351214 0.852527 0.424567 0.701987 0.287918 0.040396 0.928470 0.800661

The problem is my function TABLEAU charge_tableau(char *s, int nb_elts)

Comment: I suggest adding some error checking - you ignore the result of all the functions you should be checking as a matter of routine: `malloc`, `fopen` and `fscanf`.

Comment: Your `charge_tableau()` function ignores its argument `s`.  You should probably be using `s` (preferably renamed to `filename` or perhaps `fichier` or similar) in the call to `fopen()`.  You should probably devise a method of reporting failures to open the file.  You should error check the read operations, too.  Files frequently cause trouble — you get given 'War and Peace' to process instead of a string of numbers, for example.

Comment: The problem is the type of my array, I have put double and change parameters of the function triRapide in my main and it works. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your initial call to function `tri_rapide()`, from `main()`, passes the indeterminate values of uninitialized variables `m` and `n` as arguments.  It looks like you want this instead:

```
triRapide(t, nb_elts, 0, nb_elts);
```

Additionally, your `partition()` function declares `pivot` to have type `int`, but type `TABLEAU` is an alias for `double *`.  You therefore truncate the value of your pivot element.  For your particular data, that will truncate *all* significant digits in every case, so at each partitioning, all elements other than the pivot will be assigned to the upper partition (which, in your implementation, does not require moving them).

Note, too, that the second parameter of function `triRapide()` is absolutely useless.  You do nothing with it other than pass it on when you recurse.

Comment: Hmm, OP claimed the quicksort is working, but not with data read from file, so perhaps altered the functionality at the same time as adding the read data from file ;)